# Termux gcc compile

Tags: c, pointers

Currently I am learning C language in termux
When i try to compile a simple code of pointers  using gcc pointer.c
The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


 int a=57;

 printf("The value of a is %d \n",a);
   printf("The address of a is %u\n",&a);



return 0;

}
```

Then I got this error (actually warning) as shown in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtxGW.png)

But i see that it compiled my code and it successfully running as shown in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2spm.png)

I want to know why it gives error

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant languages, only the language you're actually program in. And copy-paste text *as text* into your question. That includes error messages. Also, the code and the error are totally unrelated to your choice of terminal.

Comment: As for the "error" (which is really only a warning) that's because pointers must be printed with the `%p` format.

Comment: Lastly please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%p` instead of `%u` to display pointer address. Your code will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a=57;
 printf("The value of a is %d \n",a);
 printf("The address of a is %p\n",&a);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks julian . Have you ever used to compile c language code in termux ?

Comment: No, I don't use temux

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
     int a=57;
     printf("The value of a is %d \n",a);
     printf("The address of a is %p\n",(void*)&a);
     return 0;
    }
```

The address of a variable is an integer numeric quantity and the format specifier used to print such a quantity is `%p` **(for printing address in hexadecimal form)** and `%lld` **(for printing address in decimal form)**. To print the address of a variable, we use `&` along with the variable name.The `%p` specifier expects a `void*`.

Comment: I think you mean `&a`, not `&p`, but it should really be `(void *)&a` to be completely legal (`%p` needs a `void *` argument). `%lld` should not be used for printing pointers, but you could use `printf("The address of a is %" PRIdPTR "\n", (intptr_t)(void *)&p);` to print the address in decimal form (after `#include <inttypes.h>`).

Comment: I meant `printf("The address of a is %" PRIdPTR "\n", (intptr_t)(void *)&a);` of course. :)